# What does > * select in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

HTML CODE:

```
<slider>
  <slide><p>Slide 1</p></slide>
  <slide><p>Slide 2</p></slide>
  <slide><p>Slide 3</p></slide>
  <slide><p>Slide 4</p></slide>
</slider>
```

CSS CODE:

```
slide > * {
  can you please tell me what this will select
}
```

Comment: I guess `slide` will be the class of your `Slide`. `slide > *` would select any nested element but you should google this. That question should not be on Stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will select all children of all `<slide>` elements. So something like this:

```html
<slide>
  <div>Selected</div>
  <div>Selected
    <div>Not selected</div>
  </div>
  <span>Selected</span>
</slide>
<slide>
  <p>Selected</p>
</slide>
```

The children (but not grandchildren) of the elements are selected.